# Where does the denominator vanish to in the MAP derivation?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, estimators, map-estimation

According to MAP estimator:
$$\hat\theta_\text{MAP}=\arg\max_\theta P(\theta|D) = \arg\max_\theta \frac{P(D|\theta)P(\theta)}{P(D)}=\arg\max_\theta {P(D|\theta)P(\theta)} $$

The denominator $P(D)$ ignored and we stay with $\arg\max_\theta {P(D|\theta)P(\theta)}$.

Why is the denominator ignored? Is it equal to 1?

Comment: The denominator merely establishes the units of measurement on the y axis when plotting the density.  Imagine that the labels on that axis have been made unreadable (but you can still read the x (value) axis labels): can you still spot where the maxima occur and read their values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$P(D)$ is constant with respect to $\theta$; so $\frac1{P(D)}$ as a constant factor doesn't change the argmax of the objective function; where $\frac{P(D|\theta)P(\theta)}{P(D)}$ has a maximum, so does ${P(D|\theta)P(\theta)}$, and vice versa.

So, optimizing one is the same as optimizing the other. Very standard trick! Constant factors, summands and other strictly monotonous functions (like $\ln, e^\cdot$) don't affect the position of the maximum.